# sql: optimize query with many conditions

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, patindex

I have this `sql` query:

```
SELECT
    [Id],
    [Content]    
FROM 
    [MyTable] with (nolock)
where
    Content is not null
    and (PATINDEX('%"number" : "[0-9]%', Content) > 0
         or PATINDEX('%"number":"[0-9]%', Content) > 0
         or PATINDEX('%"number" :"[0-9]%', Content) > 0
         or PATINDEX('%"number": "[0-9]%', Content) > 0
         --del
         or PATINDEX('%"del":"[0-9]%', Content) > 0
         or PATINDEX('%"del":"[0-9]%', Content) > 0
         or PATINDEX('%"del":"[0-9]%', Content) > 0
         or PATINDEX('%"del":"[0-9]%', Content) > 0
)
```

On my server, with caches cleared, it takes more than two minutes to return around 400 rows, maybe because I have a lot of conditions with `or`.

I've created the query that way because of the possibilities of the "number" string in the `Content` column of having a space or not between ":" and "number" string or the next digit.

Is there a way to reduce from the `or` conditions?

Comment: `REPLACE(' ', '')` white space then a single `PATINDEX('%"number":"[0-9]%'` ?

Comment: Sounds like you have a lousy data structure.  You might consider fixing the data.

Comment: I am not allowed to change a space with an empty string. This data comes from the clients that integrated an api and they can send the json as they want, as long as it is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
SELECT
    [Id],
    [Content]    
FROM 
    [MyTable] with (nolock)
where
    Content is not null
    and (PATINDEX('%"number":"[0-9]%', replace(Content,' ','')) > 0
         or PATINDEX('%"del":"[0-9]%', replace(Content,' ','')) > 0)
```

and you can remove `Content is not null` part also

Comment: I am not allowed to change a space with an empty string. This data comes from the clients that integrated an api and they can send the json as they want, as long as it is valid.

Comment: @BudaGavril:  The suggestion from Vecciassignora will not make any changes to your data, it will simply look for all records that match the `PatIndex()` on the `Context` field if the spaces in there would have been removed. It's like saying `WHERE field + 5 = 10`; this would return you all records where `field` equals 5, but it would not make any changes to `field`.